# According to the halakhic prescriptions, under what circumstances a married couple of Gentiles is considered divorced?

Tags: halacha, divorce, noachide-laws

I'm an Italian son of Noah.

In the Italian legal system, as I believe in many other countries, in addition to divorce there is the legal separation between the spouses.
According to the Italian law with legal separation, which is a prerequisite for divorce, for both spouses the obligation of cohabitation and the obligation of reciprocal fidelity are extinguished:that is to say, they can legally have sex with other people, although the spouses are still married because they have not yet divorced.

In Italy legal separation between spouses is preliminary to divorce, but does not oblige spouses to divorce later, and in fact it happens that several married couples remain legally separated without divorcing.

According to the Halakhah, under what circumstances a married couple of Gentiles is considered divorced,regardless of what is established by the Laws of the Nations?

Comment: IIRC the definition of marriage and divorce for nonJewish couples is based on the laws of their location. As a result, if the state recognizes them as no longer a couple, they are considered no longer married. I do not quite understand your usage of the term separation no longer requiring fidelity. For example, in the United States, separation means  still married until the divorce is final. Please clarify what you mean. In any case, it would depend on the local law.

Comment: @sabbahillel -In Italy, when the judge pronounces the legal separation between the spouses, they are still married, since legal separation is not a type of divorce, but they are no longer legally obliged to cohabitation and mutual fidelity. After 12 months of legal separation, they can divorce if they want to

Comment: I do not understand the phrase `mutual fidelity`. In the U.S. as an example, separation means they cannot live together (or cohabit), but they are still married in the sense that they cannot cohabit with others (which is what I thought `mutual fideity` means).

Comment: If they're "no longer obligated in mutual fidelity" that may not meet the halachic standards of a marriage.

Comment: @sabbahillel -They are no longer obligated in mutual fidelity means ,in Italy, that  they can legally have sex with other people,even if they are still married because they have not yet divorced.

Comment: OK thanks. I had never heard of that concept, so I cannot comment on it.

Comment: @Amos74 Since you seem to be indicating that this question is related to you specifically (like a practical halachic decision for you to follow) I am suggesting that this question is inappropriate for this forum. You need to consult with your local, competent Orthodox Rabbi. If you are unable to locate someone, you can seek a referral from the Court for Bnai Noach set up by the nascent Sanhedrin. http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php?title=Jerusalem_Court_for_Issues_of_Bnei_Noah

Comment: @Amos74 You might also find this link with general halachic positions taken by the nascent Sanhedrin for Bnai Noach concerning marriage and sex worth reading. http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php?title=Questions_and_Answers_on_Bnei_Noah_by_Rav_Yoel_Shwartz#Marriage_and_Sex

Comment: But realize that the nascent Sangedrin is generally thought to basically be a joke. Obviously their PR presents them as a serious quasi-Sanhedrin, so it is important to realize that they are not generally taken very seriously.

Comment: How is this considered off-topic? Practical, perhaps, in light of several recent questions posted by the OP, but this is definitely about Judaism.

Comment: I agree with @DonielF.  I don't see a *psak* request in the current version of this question.  It's clearly a question about Judaism.  Consider this a non-binding vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

From first glance it seems
It is not adultery on the level that you need to be put to death by decapitation since the

Ramam says ([kings chapter 9](http://www.chabad.org/1188354/))

> When is a gentile woman considered divorced? When her husband removes her from his home and sends her on her own or when she leaves his domain and goes her own way. They have no written divorce proceedings.
>   The matter is not dependant on the man's volition alone. Whenever he or she decide to separate, they may and then, are no longer considered as married.

But there is a law to have a court so you still must behave according to the law

But there probably are more books with better details regarding the 7 laws.
After seeing the details I might see that I am wrong

Comment: -Thank you very much for the answer.However, it seems to me that the case I pointed out is different from the one  described by Rambam. In fact, here in Italy:
-The legal effects of legal separation between spouses and divorce derive from a written provision issued by the competent magistrate;                                       
-With the only legal separation between spouses, the woman can legally have sex with other men, but she can not remarry herself with anyone because she is not a divorced woman.

Comment: @Amos74 why do you think the inability to get married he's something to do with adultery, from  a Noahid law perspective?

Comment: -Because the Noachide Law forbids a Gentile to have sex with a "married woman" (see Rambam), and the wife  legally separated in Italy without subsequent divorce is still married to her husband, although she may legally have sex with others men

Comment: @Amos74 I see it like this (tell me if I am wrong) there is **1.**  Noahid (and Jewish) marriage (which the Raman explains) which means A. the wife stays by the husband and B. the husband has the right to use her for relations (sex) (**which is not our case**) and there is **2.** Italian marriage with its laws. If we recognize Italian marriage laws should we not also recognize the law that permits relations after separation? (if Italy G-d forbid recognizes Gay marriage I do not think that has any affect on the Noah'id law)

Comment: -In fact for me it is a real puzzle ... I see to get the opinion of an Italian orthodox rabbi, if I can have it (I live in Sicily, where there are no rabbis). I will keep you informed. Meanwhile, thank you for your precious contribution!

Comment: @Community - I was able to obtain on this case a response issued by an important Italian Orthodox rabbi, a member of the Italian Rabbinical Council. Can I publish it as an answer to my own question?

Comment: @Amos74 I think you can

Comment: @Amos74 but not now since it's on hold, first you need to make the question Not personal , but theoretical

Comment: @Amos74 maybe you can just tell me what the Rabbi said, i would appreciate it

Comment: Of course, I thank you for your interest. I was able to contact the Italian Orthodox Rabbi Elia Enrico Richetti, a member of the Italian Rabbinical Council, who wrote to me: "In the case of Gentiles spouses is irrelevant, on the halachic level, that the Italian Law provides for "written divorce"; in fact, for the Jewish Law ,the separation between two Gentiles spouses is equivalent to divorce, because it  leads to the termination of the obligations concerning  the relative marriage, without the need for a written document ".

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand why the question was closed: I  requested an opinion for reasons of study, not for personal interest.

Comment: @Amos74 thank you very much. I agree it is unclear why it is closed